# What's the difference between AVO and DDG?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

When providing battle support, units offer AVO, which is Avoidance.  I know it directly lowers enemy's chance to hit.

But units can also increase DDG.  I can't find anything in the in-game help about what it does, or what it stands for.  Presumably, it's meant to be short for Dodge, but I've seen supports offer both AVO *and* DDG, which leads me to believe that's not what it is.

What is DDG, and what does it do?  If it differs from AVO, what is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right that DDG is short for `Dodge`. It's similar but different then `Avoid`.

`Avoid` is used to avoid/dodge `Normal` hits, like you stated correctly. With higher `AVO` you have a lower chance to  get hit at all.

`Dodge` is used to avoid/dodge `Critical` hits. So with an increased `Dodge`, you have less chance to get critical hitted, while NOT reducing the chance to get hit at all.

Comment: Oh, so it's an addon to Luck, which does exactly that.  Interesting.  I don't usually notice their crit chance disappearing, as it's almost always zero anyways.